# text2vec word embeddings : compound some tokens but not all

Tags: nlp, tokenize, word-embedding, text2vec

I am using {text2vec} word embeddings to build a dictionary of similar terms pertaining to a certain semantic category.

Is it OK to compound some tokens in the corpus, but not all? For example, I want to calculate terms similar to “future generation” or “rising generation”, but these collocations occur as separate terms in the original corpus of course. I am wondering if it is bad practice to gsub "rising generation" --> "rising_generation", without compounding all other terms that occur frequently together such as “climate change.”

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already tried to read what is described in this question? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22572/how-can-i-get-semantic-word-embneddings-for-compound-terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. It may or may not work exactly the way you want but it's worth trying.

You might want to look at the code for [collocations](http://text2vec.org/collocations.html) in text2vec, which can automatically detect and join phrases for you. You can certainly join phrases on top of that if you want. In Gensim in Python I would use the [Phrases](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html) code for the same thing.

Given that training word vectors usually doesn't take too long, it's best to try different techniques and see which one works better for your goal.